# PHP string manipulation with LDAP value

Tags: php

I have an array usergroup and I am echoing the values using for loop, the issue is there's one value that looks like this

```
'CN=WebHelpDesk,OU=Groups,OU=Something,DC=someCompany,DC=org'
```

an array to be exact,

```
'CN=WebHelpDesk1,OU=Groups,OU=Something,DC=someCompany,DC=org'
'CN=WebHelpDesk2,OU=Groups,OU=Something,DC=someCompany,DC=org'
'CN=WebHelpDesk3,OU=Groups,OU=Something,DC=someCompany,DC=org'
```

All I want from this string is the value of CN,

I succeeded removing the "CN=" using this line

```
$snip = substr($_SESSION['userGroup'][$i], "3");
```

the problem now is that how can I am remove the strings after the value for "CN=" since the values doesn't have a static length size.

Comment: Use explode to split the string into variables by ',' as separator. Then you can us substr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$data = "CN=WebHelpDesk,OU=Groups,OU=Something,DC=someCompany,DC=org";
$tmp = explode(",", $data);
$assoc = array();
foreach($tmp as $t){
    $values = explode("=", $t);
    $assoc[$values[0]] = $values[1];
}
// Now get wahtever value you from the $assoc array, i.e.
echo $assoc['CN'];
```

Answer (score 0):

A [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) would be the most versatile and easiest way to extract the information, though it does have a bit of a learning curve:

```
preg_match('/CN=(.*?),/', $string, $matches);
```

The CN should now be contained in the $matches array. You could also use a substring check:

```
$cn = substr($string, 2, strpos($string, ','));
```